# Alert box doesn't show even after return false

Tags: javascript, html, stoppropagation

See code:

```
area.onkeydown = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;

    if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 32){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        // no alert here

        return false;
    }
};
```

Here, the code works, and on pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, the space doesn't get inserted. However, as soon I insert an `alert`, it doesn't work, i.e. the space gets inserted and the alert box also doesn't show.

```
area.onkeydown = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;

    if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 32){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        alert("typed"); // this alert doesn't show
        return false; // and space also gets insrted
    }
};
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ34D/1/)**

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

1. Using `onkeyup` would show the alert, but a space gets inserted.
2. Using `onkeypress` would not insert the space, but the alert stays as long as the keys remain pressed.

So, I guess there is no way for me to get this working. And as [Teemu puts it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485306/alert-box-doesnt-show-even-after-return-false/24485351?noredirect=1#comment37902990_24485306):

> At your fiddle the snippet works with or without `alert()` without printing the space in IE11 (Win7). FF loses the `preventDefault()` behavior, though I can see the alert. In Chrome35 the alert only flashes on the screen and the space is printed. (If the flash is fast enough, your case?) **IE uses an OS window to show an alert, other browsers have their own implementation, which seems to mess up the event handling.**

**UPDATE:** I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can no longer be reproduced, the way it was described, in that fiddle in the latest Chrome version. Pressing Shift+Space now shows the alert box but does NOT insert any space.

Comment: If I leave [Shift]+[Space] pressed I can see the alert. Chrome @ win7

Comment: @Mark That's interesting, but why does it behave this way?

Comment: Works with Firefox 17 @ winXP, this is an interesting behavior as we apparently all use a different browser & OS

Comment: I think @user3241019 is right with this. At your fiddle the snippet works with or without `alert()` without printing the space in IE11 (Win7). FF loses the `preventDefault()` behavior, though I can see the alert. In Chrome35 the alert only flashes on the screen and the space is printed. (If the flash is fast enough, your case?) IE uses an OS window to show an alert, other browsers have their own implementation, which seems to mess up the event handling.

Comment: @Teemu That's an interesting summary. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can no longer be reproduced, the way it was described, in that fiddle in the latest Chrome version. Pressing Shift+Space now shows the alert box but does NOT insert any space.

Answer (score 2):

i've change your `keydown` to `keyup`

[See this](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ34D/2/)

`area.onkeyup = function(e){}`

Comment: i'm guessing that on keydown. while you're still holding the [shift] key. it triggers the `keydown` event. and the focus of an `alert()` when i pops up is in the `button`  so it triggers to close the alert

Answer (score 2):

Try with `onkeypress` instead of `onkeydown`

Comment: Why should I? How would it work? What's the difference between having `onkeypress` than `onkeydown` in this context?

Comment: @HamedAliKhan `onkeypress` does not work here! The intended behavior is to prevent the default action, `onkeypress` (or `onkeyup`)  is not cancelable, the space will be printed.

Comment: @Teemu, try it at http://jsfiddle.net/FZ34D/1/ and see that it will not print space, FYI I am using Chrome

Comment: Yeah, just a fun detail, you've to keep the space pressed to read the alert, probably not what OP wants. Also not working in FF ...

Answer (score 1):

Using Keyup instead of keydown reason is as below:

```
 area.onkeyup = function(e){
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ34D/4/)

**[Keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/):**

> The keydown event is sent to an element when the user **first presses a
>   key on the keyboard**. It can be attached to any element, but the event
>   is only sent to the element that **has the focus**. Focusable elements can
>   **vary between browsers**, but form elements can always get focus so are
>   reasonable candidates for this event type.

**[Keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/):**

> The keyup event is sent to an element when the user **releases a key on
>   the keyboard**. It can be attached to any element, but the event is only
>   sent to the element that **has the focus**. Focusable elements can vary
>   between browsers, but form elements can always get focus so are
>   reasonable candidates for this event type.

Comment: Ok thanks for digging up the definitions, but I am still clueless on why that works, the definitions only vary in the words "first presses"/"releases"

Comment: Notice, that jQuery has its own event handling model, OP is using vanilla JavaScript, where `onkeyup` is not cancelable.